# Is it possible to calculate a direction vector without sqrt?

Tags: mathematics, vector, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm not using Unity or any other library for making game logic. I'm making a basic game logic that needs to do basic vector math on the backend side.

I just wrote a direction function that needs to do `sqrt` for normalization. `sqrt` is not a performant function, so it is especially good to avoid on the backend side.

I need to know if I can make a normalizing function without `sqrt` — is there a way around it?

Do libraries like Unity's `Mathf` use `sqrt` under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a correct mathematical result (correctly rounded to within floating point precision), a square root is the way to go.

It's true that it's more expensive than a multiply, but it's still very likely *not* the bottleneck in your app's performance. Even expensive operations still cost far fewer CPU cycles than a single cache miss. And you've likely got cache misses happening more often than you normalize vectors.

To make this concrete with some numbers, let's summarize typical cycle counts for floating point operations in the magnitude ranges we tend to use, based on [timings on an Intel Core i7 CPU from this document](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Edkohlbre/floats/results/Intel_i7-6600U_summary.pdf), and [cache info from here](https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake.html) (not the exact same model, but close):

| Operation | (Approximate) Cycles |
| --- | --- |
| Addition | 5 |
| Multiplication | 5 |
| Division | 8 |
| Sqrt | 10 |
| L3 Cache Latency | 42 |

So you can do at least 4 square roots (very likely 2-4x more, due to pipelining) in the time it takes to pull in the next object to update that wasn't already hot in cache.

Trying to eliminate `sqrt` at this stage is almost certainly a premature micro-optimization. I'd bet that you're paying much greater inefficiencies in architectural choices like data layout that are far easier to change than the laws of geometry.

Very old games like Quake III used to use an *approximation* of `1/sqrt(x)` for normalizing vectors, which you can read about in [the Wikipedia article "Fast Inverse Square Root"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root), but it points out that this strategy isn't really your best option on modern hardware:

> With subsequent hardware advancements, especially the x86 SSE instruction `rsqrtss`, this method is not generally applicable to general purpose computing, though it remains an interesting example both historically and for more limited machines, such as low-cost embedded systems.

If you're normalizing big batches of vectors where the square root cost is a substantial fraction of the total computation time, you'll likely get better gains by vectorizing the code so you compute four normalizations at once, rather than trying to get clever with how you compute the square root itself.

Overall, be wary of programming by hearsay. When folks say "square root is expensive, avoid it when you can", they're mainly talking about cases where the square root is *unnecessary* to the value you care about: like comparing the length of a vector against a threshold or finding the shortest/longest vector in a collection. Those are cases where you get the same answer using squared length, so paying for a square root there is cycles burned for no improvement in accuracy. Where there's accuracy to be gained (like in getting a correct unit vector), it's worth paying the modest cost of a square root and division.